# TestElement, dispatch bubbeling event

Tags: angular

I have an event listener on a container element. I'm now trying to test that options are selected, when <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed on an input contained within.

I have tried using the following code, but found out, that this does not bubble by default, so my event listener attached to the container (– parent) is never reached.

```js
await testElm.dispatchEvent("keydown", { key: "enter" });
```

Of course, I've then tried:

```js
await testElm.dispatchEvent("keydown", { key: "enter", bubbles: true });
```

But that leads to an error, which supposedly is caused by how the properties are assigned to the event internally by angular:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property bubbles of [object Event] which has only a getter
```

For now, I've resorted to the following code, which for multiple obvious reasons, would be considered bad practice, so I'm hoping to change it:

```js
((testElm as any).element as HTMLInputElement).dispatchEvent(
  new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "enter", bubbles: true }),
);
```

Comment: I would not test the fact that the html element can properly dispatch events. I recommend to focus on testing the logic that you wrote; test the handler that would get executed when this event happens.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu well to trigger my logic, this event needs to happen...

Comment: I'm not testing if the element can dispatch events, I'm trying to trigger my code like the user / browser would. The actual test would then be `expect(component.value).toEqual(options[0]);` in case that is of help.

Comment: Then call the method handler for that event, with an event that you made `component.handleKeydownEvent({ key: 'Enter', which: 13, keyCode: 13 });`. This is also how the user/browser would trigger by normal use of the app.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu that would then NOT test if my event handler is correctly bound. In addition, this is not public interface, but protected, so technically impossible to call. If that is the only solution, I would argue that my orginal hack is better than that. (declaration: `protected onPanelKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent)`)

Comment: *event handler is correctly bound* should not be a concern of your app, just assume it is correctly bound. You are not building an app that bounds events to controls. That's Angular's job, or something else's job. Anyway, if you want to test that the HTML controls properly dispatch events, and that your handlers are properly bound, then I also believe your hack is probably one of the best solutions for this.

Comment: Of course it's my job to add the following code to the template: `(keydown)="onPanelKeydown($event)"`... I **do** want to include that in my tests.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but it is added, obvious inside of the template, not something you should test. You should indeed make sure that `onPanelKeydown` does what it is supposed to, test that one. Secondly, `onPanelKeydown` should be public in order to be accessible from the template, so I don't see why `component.onPanelKeydown({ whatever event here})` won't work. If you want to make sure you or somebody else does not remove that by mistake, then the solution you included in your question is perfectly fine for it.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu If that is not added my code doesn't work, and the tests should detect that :) If you disagree with that, that's okay. My question is simply how I can dispatch a bubbling event, nothing more.